# HTML Submit Button on same line as text but needs to be aligned to the right

Tags: html

I have this which lists each user and gives a button that you can press

```
echo "ID: <font color='white'>",$id0,"</font> - <a href='viewprofile.php?userid=$id0'><font        color='$namecolor'>",$username34,"</font></a> <input style=align: right' type='submit' name='battle' value='Battle' /> <br> ";
```

For reference, $id0 is the user ID, $username34 is their username.

It's supposed to list their ID, then username and I want a button on the SAME line that you can click, but I also want it to be aligned on the right.

Closest I've got is making it a form but it shows like this:
[image]

Which isn't on the same line, so I removed the form bit and now it shows like this
[image]

I know this is possible, but I don't know what I'm missing, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of align:right try float:right in css

```
echo "ID: <font color='white'>",$id0,"</font> - <a href='viewprofile.php?userid=$id0'><font        color='$namecolor'>",$username34,"</font></a> <input style='float: right' type='submit' name='battle' value='Battle' /> <br> ";
```

Comment: I tried that already, but tried it again and well..http://imgur.com/DtB56oj :P I think it might be something to do with the breaks (<br>) I use? IF I put a "<br>" before the "<input" bit, it looks like my first screenshot again. Just seems like it doesn't want to align on a line with text

Comment: Could you please try wrapping the each row content inside div and after each row add <div style='clear:both'></div>

Comment: float propertly position next element in available space. Clear:both clears previously assigned floats.

Comment: @Ryan Mckenna mark answer right if you got the answer

Comment: @Vicky I had to wait before choosing a right answer

Comment: Hmmmm ..... true that xD .... good to know SO helped you out .... have fun programming ....